# Worker always offline in Celery flower

Tags: python, apache, websocket, celery, flower

I have `Celery` and [Flower](https://github.com/mher/flower#celery-flower) running on my server and the tasks run just fine and are correctly registered and updated for me to monitor within the Flower UI, however, the worker status is allways `Offline` no matter if I restart the workers or Flower itself, and my log file (as given by the `--log_file_prefix` option) is empty, so no errors, nothing.

The only thing I can see is that the chrome dev tools show a Websocket Handshake error as shown below:
[image: flower error in chrome dev tools]
and a message `CAUTION: Provitional headers are shown.`
[image]

I read that I need to make my server to respond with the `Upgrade: websocket` and `Connection: upgrade` headers for the Websocket handshake to be successful. I'm using apache, then I tried so by specifying the following in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mysite.conf`:

```
Header set Upgrade "websocket"
Header set Connection "upgrade"
```

but it didn't work.

Does anyone have a clue on this error? Let me know if you need any more info.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gerard,
check the kombu version.

I solved a similar problem upgrading kombu to version 3.0.21 (rel. 2014-07-07).

pip install kombu==3.0.21

I'm not sure it solves your problem but give it a try.

Comment: Accepted cause, despite the websocket error is still present, this solves the `Offline` status issue I had, as stated in a recent issue in the project repo (which I didn't find before asking this): http://git.io/eBUqDw  The websocket error seems to not have anything to do with the worker status

Comment: @Gerard One more way to solve worker status is to upgrade to latest version of flower(0.8.0)

Answer (score 1):

same behavior with celery: 4.0.2, redis: 2.10.5

solve it by update kombu and redis

```
pip install kombu --upgrade

pip install redis --upgrade
```